# Proof of the following property of the totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am a newbie at number theory and was recently introduced to  Euler's Totient Function. As I found it interesting, I decided to explore some of its properties. There are many of them on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#:%7E:text=Euler%27s%20totient%20function%20is%20a%20multiplicative%20function%2C%20meaning,group%20of%20units%20of%20the%20ring%20%E2%84%A4%2Fn%E2%84%A4%20%29.). I  was able to the prove the following properties after seeing the proof of the multiplicative nature of the function.
$$ \varphi(p_{1}^{r_{1}}p_{2}^{r_{2}}....p_{k}^{r_{k}})=(p_{1}-1)p_1^{r_1-1}(p_2-1)p_{2}^{r_2-1}.....(p_k-1)p_k^{r_k-1}$$
for $p_1,p_2....p_k$ being prime numbers.
Another one I was able to prove was
$$ \varphi(n) = n \prod_{p | n}\left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right)$$
However I am having trouble proving the following
$$ n | \varphi(a^n -1) $$ for all $ a,n > 1$

I have no clue as to how to start this proof so any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this question is asked & answered at [Prove that : $n \mid \varphi (a^{n}-1)$ $a>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1413961/602049), but it involves more abstract algebra (e.g., groups and rings), than I suspect is appropriate for answering you. Also, there's a specific case of $a = 2$ at [Euler's totient function Proof that $n\mid \varphi(2^n-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/514213/602049).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$n$ divides $\phi(a^n -1)$ where $a, n$ are positive integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398165/602049)

Comment: It does but i guess i need to dive deeper into Group Theory to understand it. Thank you for your help!